# multiprocessing a function on each input array element

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

How can I replace the following "for loop" -which returns a 1D array of 50 elements- with parallel processing where `vector_a_x` and `vector_a_y` are **1x10000** 1D numpy arrays, `matrix_b_x` and `vector_b_y` are **500x600 2D** numpy arrays, and `c` and `d` are simple float variables. I thought I could use `with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:` or `with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:` then call executor.map(), but wasn't sure how to pass all these matrix and vector inputs.

```
results= np.zeros((10000, 50))
for i in range(10000):
    results[i,:] = myfunction(vector_a_x[i], vector_a_y[i], matrix_b_x, matrix_b_y, c, d)
```

Comment: Not that multiprocessing is not needed here, but also a for loop. Just `d = arr1 * 2`

Comment: create a list of input params that your function takes so executor can map through them. `myparams = [(vector_a_x[i], vector_a_y[i], matrix_b_x, matrix_b_y, c, d) for i in range(10000)]` , `executor.map(myfunction, myparams)`